# Define $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n$ recursively

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, recursion

Let $x \neq 1$ be a real number. Define the following sum recursively:
$$
1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n
$$

**My attempt:**

Using summation notation we can write the sum as $\sum_{i=0}^{n} x^i$. Now define
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{0}x^i:=x^0=1 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i+x^n
$$
It seems to me correct because if we use the definition for $n=3$, then
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{3}x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{2}x^i+x^3=(\sum_{i=0}^{1}x^i+x^2)+x^3=((\sum_{i=0}^{0}x^i+x)+x^2)+x^3=1+x+x^2+x^3
$$
In other words, we reach the base case. However, I'm unsure if this is correct. I might have misunderstood what a recursive definition is.

Comment: Isn’t it simpler to just say $f(n) = x^n + f(n-1)$?

Comment: $f(n+1)=xf(n)+1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned as a comment, we can define the recurrence:

\begin{equation*}
f(n) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^n + f(n-1) & \quad n > 0 \\
            1 & \quad n = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: Using your recurrence you can also define $f(-1)=0$ since $f(0)=1=1+f(-1)$

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the best you can do: $a_n=x\cdot a_{n-1} + 1$

With $a_0=1$

Answer (score 3):

$$f_n(x) = 1 + x + \ldots + x^n.$$

It can be rewriten as

$$f_n(x) = 1 + x\cdot\left(1 + \ldots + x^{n-1}\right),$$

or

$$f_n(x) = 1 + x\cdot f_{n-1}(x)$$

for $n>0$ and

$$f_0(x) = 1.$$

Comment: You forgot the base case $f_0(x) =1$

Comment: True, I edited the answer.